# How to find xpath for first child; it returns all children now

Tags: xpath

I have multiple  tag with  tag
Tried path (`//div[@class='input-group']/input[1]`), but returns all input tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first div, you have to use `[1]` for the div, too:

```
"//div[@class='input-group'][1]/input[1]"
```

This can still return more than one input, if there are several div groups. In such a case, you need to either specify which group you want

```
"//something[2]/div[@class='input-group']/input[1]"
```

or select from all the first inputs the one you want

```
"(//div[@class='input-group']/input[1])[2]"
```